# What is wrong with my dog’s butthole

Tags: defecation, dachshunds

So I just noticed tonight that she won’t lift her tail at all and it keeping it tucked close to her at all times. Wont even wag her tail which is very unlike her. She won’t let me touch it and won’t let me look at it.

[[image]] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0beao.jpg)
[image]
These were the best pictures I could get since she wouldn’t sit still. It’s like there’s these black dots all around her anus. When I first lifted her tail there was still a bit of watery soft poop stool to the hole so I wiped it off and she was very unhappy about it, tried to run away and bite me. I don’t know if I should take her in or if she is just a being a bit from someone she might have ate. Please help!

Comment: i canot see anything wrong,maybe take your dog to the vet if you think there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow up with your veterinarian.
The black dots may be from soft dried stool, or from leaky anal glands.
If it anal glands, she should have them expressed and examined.
If it is soft stool, she should be evaluated for the cause.
If the area needs to be cleaned or is raw, best to let someone handle her who can do it safely, since she has already been snappy about it.
Please tell the Veterinary staff that she has been snappy about it.